Searching for the name of a 70s/80s childrens TV series about ghosts in a big house, europe, prob. UK
This one is a probably british series about ghosts in a household. I think the hero ghost was a 10-12 yearold boy with a newsboy cap. I guess the age to be late 70s or early 80s.
The series takes place in, I think, a bigger house in town and the house is occupied by a family. The young ghost befriends the kids.
Later in the series, a ghost extinguisher comes and a meanspirited slim ghost uncle with a tophat. I think the uncle plans something nasty but he gets shreddered in the last episode by the ghost hunter. That scene was kinda tough for young me.

The programme is called ghost hunter the boy ghost was called william.
The Ghost Hunter (2000–2002)

The Ghost Hunter series revolves around Roddy and Tessa Oliver, two
  ordinary children whose lives are turned upside down when William
  Povey, a shoeshine boy from Victorian England appears in Roddy's
  bedroom as a ghost and appeals to him for help. The Ghost Hunter is
  searching for William in order to obtain 'spectral energy' which is
  only obtainable from capturing ghosts.
At first she seems concerned only to "collect" ghosts, but later her
  intentions become clear. She wants to use their energy to pass through
  Time itself and thereby have everlasting life. William's energy is
  especially high which makes him more attractive to the Ghost Hunter.
  As Roddy has second sight (the ability to see ghosts) and is the only
  person initially who can see William, he is the only person who can
  help him escape. Later, Tessa also finds she has second sight and can
  also see William. In their on-going battles, the two boys and Tessa,
  Roddy's sister, become firm friends and have many adventures together.
Although the series was a ground-breaking one for children's
  television and influenced other series which followed it, and although
  it had very high ratings, a fourth series was never commissioned, thus
  leaving some of the main protagonists, the Ghost Hunter and some of
  the children stuck in Victorian England.


Kindly provide more details. It will be better if you can explain why you think so

Sounds promising. Just how exactly was I able to watch a series from 2000 back in the early 80s?

I believe it is The Ghosts of Motley Hall
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ghosts_of_Motley_Hall has some details that line up.
From IMDB, a character list with descriptions:

Matt the eighteenth century stable-lad
Bodkin the Elizabethan Fool
Fanny the eighteenth century fop
Sir George the Victorian fogey 
the enigmatic White Lady 
their foil is the ghost-shy real estate agent Mr. Gudgin.


Thank you for your effort. I've checked it and I don't think that's it. The boy ghost had living kids as friends. Maybe the word "mansion" is wrong. I think it was a bigger house in a town. And the house was occupied by a family. I changed the question a little to be more specific.

Your answer persuaded me to dig a little further. And I found "Nobody's house" or "Spuk im Haus", which should be it. So, how about you edit your answer or make a new one and I declare it solved?

@Haunt_House No, that answer stands as it is. How about you just answer the question yourself, providing some details in which way the movie fits to the descriptions from the question?
